# Access Sibling Style Attributes In A Non-Theme Style

Tags: android, android-theme

Is it possible for an attribute to reference its sibling attributes, that is, ones that exist in the same `<style>`?

For example,

```
<style name="Widget.A">
  <item name="customBackground">something</item>
  <item name="android:background">?customBackground</item>
</style>
```

will produce an error since the `?` qualifier references only attributes which exist in applied theme, not within the same style.

This functionality is a necessity for my library in order for proper compatibility with all versions of Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the ? syntax only allows references attributes from the current theme.  You would have to re-write your style to define that value in a custom theme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had figured this would likely be the case. One quick followup: if I were to put a style XML in `values-v11` is it possible to explicitly read and manually parse it on previous API levels?

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces an error because there's no known attribute "customBackground". But you can create it by making an XML file in the same folder (`res/values/`) with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Widget.A">
        <attr name="customBackground" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This declaration tells us that you've got a style *Widget.A*, which has a parameter called *customBackground*, and in this example its valid values are references to other attributes. Of course, you can set the `format` attribute to whatever you need. Unfortunately, Android documentation doesn't contain clear description for this kind of declarations, so I advise you to look at the [attrs.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/attrs.xml;) in the Android source code.

Comment: I have already done this in the actual implementation. The example is a minimal one that just illustrates what I am attempting to accomplish.

Comment: If you declared properly that Widget.A has an attribute `customBackground`, then there shouldn't be any problems with referencing this attribute. At least I can confirm that I've made exactly the same style as in your example, and it compiles without problems. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: It will compile, however, the `?` qualifier refers to attributes that are defined in the root theme whereas I am looking to reference ones which have been defined within the same widget style. See https://github.com/JakeWharton/StackOverflowQuestion6486594

Comment: FYI, deleting GitHub project as true solution is impossible.